# Sqlite não roda mais android - app

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou com um problema em meu app, o sqlite aparentemente não está sendo executado.
Todas funções relacionadas a ele não estão funcionando, nessa aplicação uso algumas funções com base mysql externa essas estão "ok".

Vejam abaixo como é a construção de minha base:

```
package com.db;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String TAG = "DbHelper";
    static final String DB_NAME = "storefinder_db";
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    static Activity activity;

    public DbHelper(Activity act) {
        super(act.getApplicationContext(), DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories("
                + "category_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "category TEXT,"
                + "category_icon TEXT,"
                + "created_at INTEGER, "
                + "is_deleted INTEGER, "
                + "updated_at INTEGER "
                + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stores("
                + "store_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "category_id NTEGER, "
                + "created_at INTEGER, "
                + "distance TEXT, "
                + "email TEXT, "
                + "featured INTEGER, "
                + "icon_id INTEGER, "
                + "lat TEXT, "
                + "lon TEXT, "
                + "phone_no TEXT, "
                + "rating_count TEXT, "
                + "rating_total TEXT, "
                + "sms_no TEXT, "
                + "store_address TEXT, "
                + "store_desc TEXT, "
                + "store_name TEXT, "
                + "is_deleted INTEGER, "
                + "updated_at INTEGER, "
                + "website TEXT "

                + ");");


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews("
                + "review_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "created_at TEXT,"
                + "first_name TEXT,"
                + "last_name TEXT,"
                + "review TEXT,"
                + "store_id INTEGER,"
                + "updated_at INTEGER,"
                + "is_deleted INTEGER, "
                + "user_id INTEGER"
                + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ratings("
                + "rating_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," //AUTOINCREMENT
                + "created_at INTEGER,"
                + "rating TEXT,"
                + "store_id INTEGER,"
                + "updated_at INTEGER,"
                + "is_deleted INTEGER, "
                + "user_id INTEGER"
                + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS photos("
                + "photo_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," //AUTOINCREMENT
                + "created_at INTEGER,"
                + "photo_url TEXT,"
                + "store_id INTEGER,"
                + "thumb_url TEXT,"
                + "is_deleted INTEGER, "
                + "updated_at INTEGER"
                + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news("
                + "news_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," //AUTOINCREMENT
                + "created_at INTEGER,"
                + "news_content TEXT,"
                + "news_title TEXT,"
                + "news_url TEXT,"
                + "photo_url TEXT,"
                + "is_deleted INTEGER, "
                + "updated_at INTEGER"
                + ");");


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favorites("
                + "favorite_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," //AUTOINCREMENT
                + "store_id INTEGER"
                + ");");


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pedidos("
                + "pedidos_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," //AUTOINCREMENT
                + "pedidos_email TEXT,"
                + "pedidos_nome TEXT,"
                + "user_id INTEGER"
                + ");");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS categories");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favorites");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stores");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reviews");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ratings");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS photos");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS news");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favorites");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pedidos");

    }
}
```

Ela estava funcionando corretamente até eu realizar um refactore name em meu projeto hoje pela manhã. Após isso ela parou de funcionar.

O app está rodando normalmente e sem nenhum logcath porém as funções que exigem o sqlite não funcionam.

Já verifiquei todos locais que tinham o antigo nome da aplicação e corrigi todos eles, mesmo assim ainda nada de funcionar.

Alguem tem idéia do que pode ser?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, posso estar enganado, mas o `onCreate` só é chamado quando o schema é criado pela primeira vez, não mais. Seria esse o problema? Ou seria qualquer acesso a essas tabelas não estão funcionando, ao recuperar o `readableDatabase` ou `writetableDatabase`? Outra coisa que percebi é que no `onUpgrade`, você acaba dropando as tabelas, mas não recria as mesmas novamente, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Tente apagar os dados do app ou desinstala-lo e tente novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorreu porque você mudou o nome do banco e não mudou a versão, tente mudar essa parte:

```
static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
```

Para

```
static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
```

Tenha cuidado porque do jeito que seu código está, isso apagará todos os dados da versão antiga. Faça antes um backup.